# What should be the server side for a chat app?

Tags: android, server, cloud, chat

I'm trying to make a whatsapp like chat app, where I want a server to receive requests. I am thinking of making php server page. Would it be the right choice? or should i look for some cloud computing servers? Please convey some opinion..

Comment: An nice option, bit objective here, is node.js. There for you could use json across your whole backend. With no need for any convertion. Over all I think node.js is a good alternative to PhP and common webservers.

Comment: Use Erlang like WhatsApp uses!  http://www.wired.com/2015/09/whatsapp-serves-900-million-users-50-engineers/

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at socket.io, which is a websocket package for nodejs. In its documentation there is a chat server example. 
http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use NodeJs in this case. Node has a asynchronous nature, so its the best thing to use for chat apps. Its also a lot faster than PhP in most use cases. Another thing to consider is that NodeJS hosting is pretty cheap. In fact, you can use OpenShift and start testing your app for free in a redhat server.

If you wanna know more about nodejs: http://www.nodejs.org
More on Openshift: openshift.redhat.com

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a chat app like Whatsapp, use the following server that would help to build more easily.

1. **Yaws** - An Erlang-based web server that can also run as a standalone web server
2. **Lighttpd** - Another web server that is highly secure, swift, flexible and compliant with web server standards.